# How to disable the content touch in WebView without afecting the double tap zoom .

Tags: android, webview, android-websettings

Acually i wanted to load the content in the webview , which is in a xhtml file .

I want to disable the accessibility to the content . Click on the link/texts must not navigate to that particular page .

More particularly , I have the contents page of a book in the xhtml file and click on the contents must not navigate to the particular page .

```
WebView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
       return true;
    }  
});
```

Will work good but this stops the doulble tap zoom as well . I want to stop accessing the content without affecting the tap zoom .

And one more is that , what does `webview.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(false);`  refer to in webview .

Thanks in Advance .

Comment: try this for Zoom off `webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);`

Comment: this does not fit the content of the page into the screen size and also does not solve my problem .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to prevent navigations (user following links) then you need to use the [shouldOverrideUrlLoading](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) API:

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
       return true;
    }
});
```